# how to create nested routes

Tags: aurelia

I'm not finding it very obvious how to make a route with this structure:
http://localhost:9000/#/vendors/557794d4dda4a5b6162aab53/services/413jdjo53j2ojo532

In the latest blog, I am seeing references to child/parent routes and looking up parent params from the child, but in the docs, I only see references to child routers and having a whole new router seems a bit like an overkill for this use case.

What is the best way to create such a route and be able to look up data from the parent route? How do we achieve a route hierarchy (like in Ember for example)?

Comment: Difficult to debug/help with since the link points to your local machine - any chance of a screenshot?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? A lot has changed in 2 years, maybe it's time to close this question?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the easiest way to share data between child and parent route is use a shared state, just create a class

```
export class State {
    status = null
}
```

And then `inject` it into both the parent and child view models, by default it will be a singleton so you can use it to pass data around.

Comment: That would only work if you don't care (much) about the url's - when You store the state in memory and refresh the page, then the state is lost... However if You really can't/don't want to store it in url, then this problem can be solved by persisting/loading the state when refreshing the screen.

Comment: Either that or using the history API, but that's a different problem